# There's hidden JavaScript detected by W3C validator

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation

I checked my site in the W3C validator and it says that there's a `script` element in line 36 like this:

> ```
> 9EbDL' /> <script type="text/javascript"> (func
> ```

I searched in my HTML and I just found this

```
<link rel='shortlink' href='https:wp.me/9EbDL' />

<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//v0.wordpress.com'/>
```

Where is the `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Here are the links:

- https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fnews.txtbuff.com%2F
- view-source:https://news.txtbuff.com/

Comment: The script is where the validator reports it (lines 36-68) but for some reason (probably a cookie), it is inserted in the page only on the first visit. That's why you cannot see it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the page in your web browser and use the developer tools to find this (injected) JavaScript.

`View-Source:` will not evaluate Javascript-Code but show the original source that is received from your server.

It seems that one of your Javascript-files you can observe in `View-Source:`-view is responsible for adding the script-tag in question to the DOM.